# How to create shortcut to home screen to specific class with parameters

Tags: android

I have 2 classes

1. MainActivity,
2. SecondActivity

and I am creating shortcut to home screen with:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.androidapp", "SecondActivity");
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Name");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, 
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

How can I configure with this functions the on clicking the shortcut it will open SecondActivity and pass parameters to it.

Comment: Manjunba's solution won't be enough. You didn't set the class name correctly. Note that even if Eclipse/Android Studio's new project wizard shows you one package name, it actually creates two identical package names underneath (one package name for the application and one idential package name for the activity). In other words, you'll have to write shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.androidapp", "com.example.androidapp.SecondActivity");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
addIntent.putExtra("parameterName", "parameterValue");
```

And to get this after:

```
Intent addIntent= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
String parameter = addIntent.getStringExtra("parameterName"); // will return "parameterValue"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should be shortcutIntent.putExtra("parameterName", "parameterValue");